# Printing the lowest number in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

While I have seen some questions regarding the same topic, they are not specific enough to my situation.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kap3Oppg5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int tabell[] = new int[10];
    int heltall;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minstetall = tabell[0];

    while (x < 10) {
        System.out.println("Tast inn neste tall:");
        heltall = in.nextInt();
        tabell[x] = heltall;
        x = x + 1;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<tabell.length;i++) {
        if (tabell[i] < tabell[0])
            minstetall = tabell[i];

    }
    System.out.print(minstetall);
}

}
```

Why this is not printing the lowest number?

Comment: Side comment: you could use a `List<Integer>` instead of an `int[]` and call `int min = Collections.min(list);`.

Answer (score 4):

The test in your if always tests against the first element in the array. You might want to test it against the lowest number found up to that point:

```
if (tabell[i] < minstetall) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Because each time you are comparing with the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison `if (tabell[i] < tabell[0])` is wrong it should be:

```
if (tabell[i] < minstetall)
```

You are comparing against the first element. **Currently if your array's first element contains the lowest value by chance then you will get the correct result**, otherwise the current code would fail.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in this line you are comparing the wrong thing:

```
if (tabell[i] < tabell[0])
```

should be

```
if (tabell[i] < minstetall)
```